# Finding the angle between the 3D view vector and normal-Back face culling

Tags: matlab

Finding the angle between the view vector and the surface normal can be beneficial in getting the visible surfaces since we use it to conduct back face culling techniques and obtaining contours, crease edges of the object.

To obtain the visible surfaces I use the back face culling code below:

```
N = normals(vertex,faces);
BC = barycenter(vertex,faces);
back_facing = sum(N.*bsxfun(@minus,BC,campos),2)<=0
t.FaceVertexCData = 1*(sum(N.*bsxfun(@minus,BC,campos),2)<=0)
t.FaceVertexCData(sum(N.*bsxfun(@minus,BC,campos),2)>0) = nan;
faces1=faces(t.FaceVertexCData(:)==1,:);
facesv=sort(unique(faces1(:)));
```

How does one obtain the angle?

```
r=(sum(N.*bsxfun(@minus,BC,campos),2))
rr=bsxfun(@minus,BC,campos);
V_mag= sqrt(rr(:,1).^2+rr(:,2).^2+rr(:,3).^2);
N_mag= sqrt(N(:,1).^2+N(:,2).^2+N(:,3).^2);


for i = 1:(size(r,1)) 
    A(i)=acosd(r(i)/(N_mag(i).*V_mag(i)));
end
```

This is what I have done thus far. I am not sure if it is correct and code is slow.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to vectors, and want to find the angle between them?

Comment: yes i use two vectors.

Comment: Try to look at http://www.intmath.com/vectors/7-vectors-in-3d-space.php. It's the first result when you google "angle two 3d vectors"

Comment: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camva.html might help as well if I understand the question correctly.